# Why is "digression" pronounced with /ai/?

Tags: pronunciation

Why is "digression" pronounced  with /ai/, while other similar words (like dimension)  are pronounced with /i/? moreover, some derivatives, like digressional can be pronounced with both /ai/ and /i/? according to some of the dictionaries, both /i/ and /ai/ are acceptable, but most of the dictionaries still offer only /ai/ version.

Comment: Perhaps if "di-" is a Latin prefix, then we pronounce it with /ai/ in English.

Comment: Are *dimension* and *digression* pronounced /di-/? I'm not sure I agree. Offhand, I can't think of a Latin-derived *di-* word which BrE pronounces /di-/.

Comment: @AndrewLeach thanks for the answer. no, the thing is, they seem to be pronounced differently (dimension with /di/ and digression with /dai/), that's why I've been wondering..

Comment: @GEdgar thanks for the answer! it seems to be right:)

Comment: Related: [Why does the word dilemma have two pronunciations?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145632)

Answer (score 2):

If there's a difference in the sound of "di" in "digression" and "di" in "dimension", I suggest that's down to an individual speaker, not to any rule of English